# TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted vs try catch

Tags: c#, .net, logging, try-catch, task-parallel-library

What's the difference between

```
var task3 = Task.Run(() => PerformLongTask()).ContinueWith(t => Log.Error(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

and

```
var task3 = Task.Run(() => PerformLongTask());

private void PerformLongTask()
{
  try
  {
  //......
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     Log.Error(ex);
  }
}
```

I tried running both examples. On the surface, they appear to behave the same.

Is one approach better than the other?

Comment: Not in this snippet, assuming the Log class is thread-safe.  You tend to care that the continuation occurs on the UI thread so it problem can be reported to the user.  Then it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, they're the same. However, if you don't own the innards of "PerformLongTask", you can't wrap its contents in a try-catch either. Also, the task's Status will be set to RanToCompletion this way, even if it threw an exception. If you have a continuation on the task, it will have to deal with the antecedent task potentially not having a valid Result.

I suppose the short of it is that in the former case, your exception handling logic is contained in a separate task, decoupled from the rest.